Verifying Ubuntu ISO file
For some time now I have been wondering if verifying the PGP signature and sha256 hash are actually needed to check if there is any malware in the downloaded ISO.
Evertime I try to google this, i get the same answer: sometimes/maybe/it might be useful.
I'm trying to find a yes or no for this question since all the answeres I can find are doubtful.
So I have the folling questions:
Do I need to verify the PGP signature to be sure that my OS has not been compromised from the start?
Do I need to verify the sha256 hash to be sure that my ISO file has not been compromised?
Thanks in advance!

answer depends on your appetite for risk ... very often where you download the ISO from will also display the corresponding hash value so once the download finishes in a terminal issue the command to run a hash and if the value matches then you are OK ... there is no hard and fast requirement for this ... doing so gives you confidence acknowledging the owner of the site where you did the download is not themselves malicious ... moral of story always download from trusted sites not from suspect ones ...  download Ubuntu directly from  https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop or https://ubuntu.com/

I have personally not bothered - and I have not heard about anyone impersonating a legitimate mirror yet. Verification is nice, but so far there's been more upstream attacks ala xz than against iso image distribution.

Think DNS cache poisoning -- your "secure site" gets switched for a malware site under the hood (and of course their hashes have been adjusted).  Solution: pgp, but it goes on from there, back channel fingerprint checking of your key, ..... As Scott said, depends upon your appetite for risk.

Checking the SHA256SUM tells you if the .iso (really, any file) tells you if the file has been corrupted (any corruption, not only malware) along its path to your system. Checking the PGP signature  lets one verify the identity of the SHA256SUM provider. Do you need to verify these? Yes, always. From 55+ years sysadmin experience.
